# How to enrich metric data using external sources?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

**Example**

I am getting a series for a metric with a label called `store` which contains the `storeId`. Now I would like to add another label `storeName` and fill it with external information (`API-call/CSV/other Prometheus "metric"/merging from mysql/...`). Is this possible? If so, in which ways?

**Goal**

To show the resulting metric in Grafana graph panels so that it contains names rather than IDs.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: No. The only way I know to achieve this would be something like a decorator service between source and prometheus or between prometheus and grafana - depends on the goal..

Answer (score 1):

Current versions of Grafana support interpretation of time series as tables. This way those can be join similarly to join of SQL.

In panel editor, under the query: Options > Type: `Table`. This should be done for both queries if you are joining Prometheus data with another Prometheus data.

Then Transform tab > Join by field: select common filed of your data.

There is a catch though: filed should have same name in both datasets, and only one field allowed for joining.